# Initialize jQuery?

Tags: jquery, velocity.js

I am trying to use [velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/) to rotate a `div`.
When I code it in [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYKoVB) it works with no problem but when I try to run it in my [html](http://elcerebro.com/velocity.html) it does not. What am I doing wrong? I want to pull my hair out.

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<div id="first"></div>
```

CSS

```
#first {
   width:300px;
   height:300px;
   background-color: red;
}
```

JS

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#first").velocity({ rotateZ: 360 }, {
    duration: 6000, loop:true
    easing: [ 0.80, 0.80, 0.80, 0.70 ];
  });
});`
```

Using velocity library at:
http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/velocity/1.1.0/velocity.min.js

Comment: What is the error/problem/etc.?

Comment: This question is neither relevant to jQuery, nor to Velocity.js. It's a simple JS syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object has a syntax error

```
easing: [ 0.80, 0.80, 0.80, 0.70 ];
```

should not have a semicolon.

```
loop:true
```

needs a comma after it